# Spring profile injection: don't inject a class without a profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Let's say I'm using Spring for my Java project and I have the following interface and classes:

```
public interface MyInterface { ... }

@Component
public class MyInterfaceMainImpl implements MyInterface { ... }

@Component
@Profile("mock")
public class MyInterfaceMockImpl implements MyInterface { ... }

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:my-context.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"mock"})
public class MyInterfaceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Inject
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    ...
}
```

Assume that *my-context.xml* enables component scanning on the package that contains my interface and its implementation classes. When I specify the profile as "mock", I get an error that says something like this: "expected single matching bean but found 2:...".

Any idea how I can avoid having my non-profile method from being a matching bean during injection? Or is the only possible solution to give that main implementation class a profile too? That was the solution I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

- Use `@Primary` to indicate that `MyInterfaceMockImpl` is preferred when both implementations are present:

  ```
  @Component
  @Primary
  @Profile("mock")
  public class MyInterfaceMockImpl implements MyInterface { ... }
  ```
- Use `@Profile` with negation to exclude main implementation when `mock` is active:

  ```
  @Component
  @Profile("!mock")
  public class MyInterfaceMainImpl implements MyInterface { ... }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use @Qualifier to specify which one

```
@Component("main")
public class MyInterfaceMainImpl implements MyInterface { ... }

@Component("mock")
public class MyInterfaceMockImpl implements MyInterface { ... }



@Inject
@Qualifer("mock")
private MyInterface myInterface;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to annotate both implementations with `@Profile`, and provide different names for each.

```
@Component 
@Profile("mock")
public class MyInterfaceMockImpl implements MyInterface { ... }

@Component
@Profile("default")
public class MyInterfaceMainImpl implements MyInterface { ... }
```

The advantage of this approach is that it allows you to specify `default` as one of the profiles in the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation on your test class. Not terribly useful in this contrived example, of course, but it scales nicely if you have three or more profiles that you want to use in different tests.